# Map to Obejct Javascript convert in REACTJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, dictionary

I want to convert following Map to Object in REACTJS
How can I achieve this

```
[
      {
        "lastName": "Last name should have atleast 1 characters "
      },
      {
        "role": "may not be null"
      },
      {
        "name": "Name should have atleast 1 characters "
      }
    ]
```

convert to

```
{
  "lastName": "Last name should have atleast 1 characters ",
  "role": "may not be null",
  "name": "Name should have atleast 1 characters "
}
```

Comment: This is very irregular structure. You should fix it in the first place ideally.

Comment: In first Code snippet, I used Map,  but I want the second Snippet like structure , can you please help me with an example in codepen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a nested reduce but keys earlier in the array will be overwritten by later ones if the key in the array is not unique:

```js
console.log(
  [
    {
      lastName:
        'Last name should have atleast 1 characters ',
    },
    {
      role: 'may not be null',
    },
    {
      name: 'Name should have atleast 1 characters ',
    },
  ].reduce((mainResult, item) =>
    Object.entries(item).reduce(
      (result, [key, value]) => (
        (result[key] = value), result
      ),
      mainResult,
    ),
    {}
  ),
);
```

Seeing your answer (you should comment instead of adding an answer) it looks like your array is an array of JSON strings, try the following:

```js
console.log(
  //array of json strings
  [
    '{"lastName":"Last name should have atleast 1 characters "}',
    '{"role":"may not be null"}',
    '{"name":"Name should have atleast 1 characters "}',
  ]
    .map((item) => JSON.parse(item))
    .reduce((mainResult, item) =>
      Object.entries(item).reduce(
        (result, [key, value]) => (
          (result[key] = value), result
        ),
        mainResult,
      ),
      {}
    ),
);
```

Comment: Why not cut out the `map()` and just `JSON.parse()` within the `reduce()`?

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) can be leveraged to create objects from arrays.

See below for a practical example.

```js
// Input.
const input = [{lastName: 'Last name should have atleast 1 characters'}, {role: 'may not be null'}, {name: 'Name should have atleast 1 characters '}]

// Convert Array To Object.
const convertArrayToObject = array => array.reduce((acc, x) => {
  for (const key in x) acc[key] = x[key]
  return acc
}, {})

// Output + Proof.
const output = convertArrayToObject(input)
console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the array to change its shape to the desired object

```js
const a = [
  {
    "lastName": "Last name should have atleast 1 characters "
  },
  {
    "role": "may not be null"
  },
  {
    "name": "Name should have atleast 1 characters "
  }
];

const b = a.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: item[key],
  };
}, []);

console.log(b);
```